# I'm trying to create a new column with the MAX Value from a Range of Months in the data frame but the condition is to get max value for first 3 month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

[image]

This is the data format date column shows the first entry date and i am trying to get the max of due missed in the first  3 months and i have data of 30 months and i need max of dues missed in the first 3 months for each id

Comment: I tried python groupby but it's giving me max of 30 months ,is there any other alternative solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Also edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input dataframes and expected output so that we can better understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your dataframe, as shown in your picture:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[100,100,100,100,100,
          101,101,101,101, 101],
    'Entry Date':['2020-04-10','2020-05-10','2020-06-10','2020-07-10','2020-08-10',
                  '2020-07-25','2020-08-25','2020-09-25','2020-10-25','2020-11-25'],
    'Due missed':[0,0,7,0,5,
                  9,1,5,7,10]
})
df['Entry Date'] = df['Entry Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

What you will want to do is sort the dataframe so the first 3 months are at the top per ID:

```
df.sort_values(['ID', 'Entry Date'], inplace=True)
```

Then you can group by ID and select the top 3 rows (using `head(3)`), and select the maximum value of those three rows (using `['Due missed'].max()`):

```
df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.head(3)['Due missed'].max())
```